# Pie in ggraphics window. Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am trying to build a GUI to display some results. As part of this I want to automatically display a pie char of the results. So the simplified extract is below:

```
library("gWidgets2")
library("cairoDevice")

pieBits=c(0.1,0.9)
lab <- c("Some text", "More text")
win <- gwindow(title="title", width=1000, height=800, expand=TRUE)
notebook <- gnotebook(container = win)
lyt3 <- ggraphics(height=500, width=500,ps=6,
                  container = notebook, label="JUNK")
visible(lyt3)
pie(pieBits, labels = lab, radius=0.1, par(mar = rep(0.1,4)))
```

The window is large, graphic container large but smaller than the window and the pie is small with small margins. So why will this not work? What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't run your code, but this usually happens as the graphics device isn't drawn before the graphics device is called upon. Maybe sleeping a bit before the `pie` command will help. There are fancier solutions such as rendering the first graphic using the signal indicating the window is realized.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as stated in the previous comment, the graphic device seems not to be ready yet when plot is invoked.
Even if it is not a "proper" solution, a quick fix I use is to add a small sleep like this:

```
win<-gwindow(title = "My window",width = 800)
add(win,ggraphics())
Sys.sleep(.3)
plot(.......)
```

Hope it helps